# How do I return the second instance of a substring in Java?

Tags: java

I'm making a function that returns the second occurrence of a character the user inputs. The problem is that it's not printing anything. I remember hearing something about using a nested for loop for it but I don't know. Here's the program; the function I'm having problems with is the last one.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class IntroToWHILELoops
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        //Thiis section tests the first method
        String myString = GetAndStoreInput();
        System.out.println(myString);
        
        //This section tests the second method
        System.out.println("Enter a character to search for --> ");
        String searchChar = System.console().readLine();
        int position = SecondCharPosition(myString,searchChar);
        System.out.println("The second position of " +searchChar +" is " +position);
                
    }
    
    //This method keeps getting input from the user until a "X" or "x" is entered
    //It then stores the input in a string.
    public static String GetAndStoreInput()
    {
      String input;
      String sentence = "";
      
      input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something (press x to stop)");

        while(!input.equals("x")  && !input.equals("X") ){
        System.out.println(input);
        
        sentence = sentence + input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something else (press x to stop)");
      }
      return sentence;
        
    }
    
    
    //Given a string, this method returns the position of the second occurrence of a given character.
    //If the character occurs less than 2 times it returns -1.
    public static int SecondCharPosition(String str, String Charr)
    {
      String sentence = str;
      int count = 1;
      int position = 0;
      int i = 0;
      while(count < 10){
          if(sentence.substring(i,i+1).equals(Charr)){
          count++;
        }
          if(count == 2){
          position = i;
        }
      }
      return position;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to increment `i` to loop over the characters.

Comment: If your counter starts at one then it will be two after you find just one match.

Comment: @shawn incrementing i is just doing i++, right? Where should I put it?

Comment: Java naming conventions have classes start with an upper case letter; methods and variables start with lower case letter (ex. getAndStoreInput()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tyler - Hope this helps you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Thiis section tests the first method
        String myString = GetAndStoreInput();
        System.out.println(myString);

        // This section tests the second method
        System.out.println("Enter a character to search for --> ");
        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchChar = in.next();
        int position = SecondCharPosition(myString, searchChar);
        System.out.println("The second position of " + searchChar + " is " + position);

    }

    // This method keeps getting input from the user until a "X" or "x" is entered
    // It then stores the input in a string.
    public static String GetAndStoreInput() {
        String input;
        String sentence = "";

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something (press x to stop)");

        while (!input.equals("x") && !input.equals("X")) {
            System.out.println(input);

            sentence = sentence + input;
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something else (press x to stop)");
        }
        return sentence;

    }

    // Given a string, this method returns the position of the second occurrence of a given character.
    // If the character occurs less than 2 times it returns -1.
    public static int SecondCharPosition(String str, String Charr) {
        int count = 0;
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (String.valueOf(str.charAt(i)).equals(Charr))
                count++;

            if (count == 2) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }
}
```